# iOS CGContextSetRGBFillColor too few arguments

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I am building a PDF generator class in my app and setting up methods for drawing text, lines and images...

for some reason I can't seem to pass a UIColor with a CGColor conversion to CGContextSetRGBFillColor, but I can pass one to CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor.

Here's the relevant portions of my code:

```
CGContextSetRGBFillColor(currentContext, textColor.CGColor);
```

am I missing something as to why one will convert but the other won't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CGContextSetRGBFillColor()` takes the components as individual arguments. You want `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor`.

Comment: Thanks Nikolai...I just found this in the docs as well. Dang it. : D